# How to put the asterisk on the end of max function rather than right above it

Tags: math-mode

I am writing my report using TeXnicCenter, and it has been going very well.

However, I want to write max* in the equation mode, but all i code get is the asterisk right about the `a` in `max`

if I write `$\max*$` in normal inline equation I get what I want which is `max*`. but when I write it using the equation command which is

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq:a}
\max^{*}(a,b)
\end{equation}
```

I get max(a,b) and the astrik is right above 'a', like I am using `\limits`. using `\mbox` will put the asterisk way after the `max`.

this is an image showing my dilemma, it shows what I want, then what I get for using `\mbox{*}` then what I get for using `\max^*`

[image: picture]

Answer (score 4):

What you want is a new math operator; however there's a slight TeXnical complication with a naïf `\DeclareMathOperator` and `^{\ast}` should be used instead of `^{*}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\smax}{max^{\ast}}

\begin{document}

\[
\smax_{(s'\to s)\Rightarrow u_{i}=1}\bigl(\tilde{\delta}_{i}(s',s)\bigr)
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the amsmath `\newmcodes@` should have gotten a lifting ... (and happy users of `mathastext` get it for free -- although I went a bit too radical, and at some point should make it better).

Comment: @jfbu What they want to avoid is `*` used as a binary operation symbol, but the result is that it becomes a raised asterisk as in text. I tried `\DeclareMathOperator{\smax}{max*}`, but the asterisk comes out different from the math mode one (at least in the CM fonts).

Comment: for the  CM fonts, it seems the difference is only one of size : `\DeclareMathOperator{\smax}{max{\scriptstyle*}}` produces visually a glyph very similar to the math `*` (but not raised enough...) . Using `\ast` is clearly the good workaround.

Comment: amsmath could have done ``\count255\mathcode`\* \divide\count255 "1000  \multiply\count255 -"1000 \advance\count255 \mathcode`\*\mathcode`\* \count255 ``

Comment: but that would have been a problem with a math active `*` ...

Comment: @jfbu Yes, of course. But using `\ast` solves the issue.